# How do I get multiple balls to move randomly in pygame using self and other?

Tags: python, pygame

Ok so I am new to both Stack Overflow and Python and I am using Pygame to make a game where a bunch of randomly colored balls are spawned, and they will hopefully move randomly and when they collide will become bigger and take the "average" of the color by using the integers of the r g and b values. My current problem is that I have the balls spawned but I can not get the balls to move. I am trying to get them to move in an update function in my ball class. I want them to move randomly as they move without user input.

This is my main

```
import pygame
import random
import ballClass

WORLD_WIDTH = 800
WORLD_HEIGHT = 600


WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT))

paused = False

def main():
    global numberOfBalls, WIN, paused

    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

    #ballClass.Ball().initialize(10)
    

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
          
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False

          elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
              paused = not paused

          if not paused:
            WIN.fill(WHITE)
            
            ballClass.Ball().draw(WIN)
            ballClass.Ball().update(WIN)
              #drawWorld(WIN)


        clock.tick(1)

        pygame.display.update()
    

def setInitialBallAttributes():
    pass

#def checkForCollision(self): #iterate through list of objects and check each one against , tell it to do averaging
#     ball1 = self.ball
#     ball2 = self.ball
#     ball3 = self.ball
#     ball4 = self.ball
#     ball5 = self.ball

#     balls = [ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5]

#     #from Mr. Sharick
    # for i in range(len(balls)):
    #     for j in range(i, len(balls)):  # start this loop at i+1 so you don't check collisions twice
    #         balls[i].collision(balls[j])



#def drawWorld(WIN, self):
#     ball1 = self.ball
#     ball2 = self.ball
#     ball3 = self.ball
#     ball4 = self.ball
#     ball5 = self.ball
  #pygame.draw.rect(WIN, 'black', width=0)
  #pass



if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

and this is my ballClass

```
import pygame
import random
import math

balls = []

center1 = random.randint(0,600)
center2 = random.randint(0, 600)

balls.append((center1, center2))

class Ball():

    WORLD_WIDTH = 600
    WORLD_HEIGHT = 600

    def __init__(self, centerX=None, centerY=None, direction=None, r=None, g=None, b=None, radius= None, speed= None):
        self.centerX = 10
        self.centerY = 20
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b
        self.direction = direction  
        self.radius = radius
        self.speed = 3 #Set as default 3; change later

    
    def initialize(self, num):
      global balls
      for i in range(num):

        self.centerX = random.randint(0, 600)
        self.centerY = random.randint(0,600)

        balls.append((self.centerX, self.centerY))


    def draw(self, WIN):
        global ball, radius, centerX, centerY, r, g, b, balls
        self.radius = 10

        self.direction = random.randint(0, 600), random.randint(0, 600)
        self.speed = 3

        #self.centerX = random.randint(self.radius, 600 - self.radius)
        #self.centerY = random.randint(self.radius, 600 - self.radius)

        r = random.randint(0, 255)
        g = random.randint(0, 255)
        b = random.randint(0, 255)

        #self.ball = Ball(centerX, centerY, radius, WIN)
        # needs all 8 
        for ball in balls:
          
          pygame.draw.circle(WIN, ((r,g,b)), (ball[0],ball[1]),self.radius)

          print(ball)

        #balls.append((self.centerX, self.centerY))

    # def collision(self, other): #pass in another ball object as another parameter
    #     distance = math.sqrt((self.centerX - self.centerY)^2 + (other.centerX - other.centerY)^2)

    #     if distance < self.radius + other.radius:
    #         (self.r + other.r) / 2 == self.r
    #         (self.g + other.g) / 2 == self.g
    #         (self.b + other.b) / 2 == self.b
    #         if self.radius > other.radius:
    #             self.radius = other.radius + self.radius
    #             other.radius = 0

    #         if other.radius > self.radius:
    #             other.radius = other.radius + self.radius
    #             self.radius = 0

    #         else:
    #             #self.radius = other.radius + self.radius
    #             self.centerX = (other.centerX + self.centerX) / 2
    #             self.centerY = (other.centerY + self.centerY) / 2
    #             other.radius = 0

    def update(self, win):
        WORLD_WIDTH = 600
        WORLD_HEIGHT = 600
        
        # if len(balls):

        #   for i in range(len(balls)):

        #     balls[i] = (center1+10, center2 +10)

      newBallCoords
        
        

        # if self.right >= WORLD_WIDTH or ball.left <= 0:
        #     self.direction = -self.centerX, self.centerX

        # if self.bottom >= WORLD_HEIGHT or ball.top <= 0:
            #self.direction = self.centerX, -self.centerX
```

I commented out stuff that was for the collision part... I am not there yet ad hoping to get the balls to move. I apologize in advance If i am using this page wrong as I am new but would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the balls to move with their own independent directions, each ball should have it's own X and Y velocities which should be generated randomly upon initialization.

Looking at the program you have included I would recommend you consider separating the Ball class from the logic of controlling all the balls.

I have included a modified version of your program that includes this idea.

Main:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import ball as ballClass

WORLD_WIDTH = 800
WORLD_HEIGHT = 600

def main():
    paused = False
    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT))

    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

    balls = [ballClass.Ball() for _ in range(8)]

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
          
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              running = False

          elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
              paused = not paused

        if not paused:
            WIN.fill(WHITE)
            
        for ball in balls:
            ball.draw(WIN)
            ball.update(WIN)   
      
        clock.tick(1) 
        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Ball

```
import random, pygame

class Ball():

    WORLD_WIDTH = 600
    WORLD_HEIGHT = 600

    def __init__(self, centerX=None, centerY=None, direction=None, r=None, g=None, b=None, radius= None, speed= None):
        self.centerX = random.randint(0, 600)
        self.centerY = random.randint(0,600)
        self.r = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.g = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.b = random.randint(0, 255)
        self.velocityX = random.randint(-10, 10)
        self.velocityY = random.randint(-10, 10)
        self.radius = 10

    def draw(self, WIN):
        pygame.draw.circle(WIN, ((self.r,self.g,self.b)), (self.centerX, self.centerY), self.radius)


    def update(self, win):
        self.centerX += self.velocityX
        self.centerY += self.velocityY
```

In the code I provided the Ball's update method only updates a single ball, with it's respective velocities, and the main program tells all the balls that they need to be updated.

Comment: There may be an indentation missing, your balls are still being updated during pause.